# Google Glass XE12 update... sample APKs not working?

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

After the XE12 update, are any of you having trouble running the sample projects (compass, stopwatch, timer)?

When I try to run them, the programs just say "(program name) has stopped".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you updated your code to the latest versions? XE12 had a number of breaking API changes (such as renamed methods and classes).

You should make sure that the APKs that you've built are from the latest source, either in the add-on's samples directory or from Github, and the reinstall them.

Comment: Do you happen to have links to them? I was building them from Eclipse > Start New Sample Project > clicked GDK.

Comment: After you updated the GDK add-on, you should probably delete the old projects and re-create them to get the latest versions. They can also be found on our Github page: https://github.com/googleglass